# How do I get a filelist from the local filesystem in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The title kind of says it, but I’ll elaborate a bit.

I use SQL Server 2005, and I'm writing an export query that’ll return a list of users. Some users have profile images, some don’t. The profile image is not represented in the database, at all. There’s just a file on the filesystem, named [username].jpg. So what I need to do is to check if such a file exists for the user.

Comment: Is there any good reason for you to do this in SQL at all? I'd use a more expressive programming language that features both a file system and a databases access layer.

Comment: The initial idea was to solve it with SQL, but from the answers so far I'm getting the feeling it's not a great idea. ;) I may have to look into some other solution. The reason for doing it in SQL was the easy to call it from a web interface. I may be better off doing it with SSIS instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you must you could always do the following

```
DECLARE  @fso int,
         @hr int
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @fso OUT
```

From that you may (if hr=0) get a good old [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxy1a51(VS.85).aspx).

From that you should be able to do the following

```
EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @fso, 'FileExists', @hr OUT, @FileName
```

But really, for wanting to do this, you're going to hell ****grin****

Of course this depends on a lot of things, your SQL server configuration, the user it runs under, etc etc. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Going to hell, you say. I sense this solution is not what one might call best practice. Am I reading you right? :) Should I look into some other solution?

Comment: Heh. Well ActiveX inside SQL has all sorts of implications, not least security problems.

If you could rewrite the upload so it sets a flag in the database, or the filename that would be better, then update the table in a one time hit

Comment: Yes, I absolutely see your point. Might have to do that, as it feels like the most sensible solution in the end. It's just an extra bit in the DB. Either that, or I'll make some kind of SSIS package that solves it for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you must do this from within sql you could use xp_cmdshell and 'if exist'. This isn't enabled by default for security reasons, so be careful.

enable xp_cmdshell:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
reconfigure
sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
reconfigure
```

use xp_cmdshell:

```
xp_cmdshell 'if exist c:\blargh.txt echo 1'
```

Comment: Does it have to be enabled permanently, or is it possible to simply enable it while the query runs, then disable it again?
But since everyone seems to think it's bad practice, I'll probably solve it some other way.

Comment: you can enable and then disable as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [sp_OACreate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/819070/1501497) then you need to enable *'Ole Automation Procedures'*

otherwise you get the following error:

> Msg 15281, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_OACreate, Line 1 [Batch
> Start Line 0] SQL Server blocked access to procedure 'sys.sp_OACreate'
> of component 'Ole Automation Procedures' because this component is
> turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A
> system administrator can enable the use of 'Ole Automation Procedures'
> by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling 'Ole
> Automation Procedures', search for 'Ole Automation Procedures' in SQL
> Server Books Online.

[image]

```
 DECLARE @result INT
 DECLARE @path varchar(255) = 'M:\SQLLOGS\S01_one_database_CA_Log.ldf'
 EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist @path, @result OUTPUT
 SELECT  [Do the file exist?]=
         CASE WHEN cast(@result as bit) = 1 THEN 'Yes, the file Exists!' 
              ELSE 'No, the file does not exist!' 
     END
```

[image]

-- [How to find out the oldest full backup still existing on disk?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/230696/how-to-find-out-the-oldest-full-backup-still-existing-on-disk/230697#230697)

-- [Check for file exists or not in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740000/check-for-file-exists-or-not-in-sql-server)

-- [SQL Server: How to Check if a File Exists in a Directory](https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/30527/sql-server-how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-a-directory/)