# How do I check if a directory exists using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, directory, xp-cmdshell

I know this command will create a directory:

```
EXEC master.sys.xp_create_subdir 'C:\testing\'
```

But how do I check whether 'C:\testing\' exists?

```
IF EXISTS(...
```

Comment: Disagree with this being closed as not constructive.  The question is clear enough - I checked the help center to see what was legitimate reasons for closing and did not find this to match any of those reasons.  The question, while perhaps not a fully code segment, is clear enough to understand that the question asks "How do I check for existance of a subdirectory and do stuff if it exists"

Comment: I agree. Now google brings me here as one of the first hits and the info is very concise and spot-on.

Comment: Yet another ludicrous "not constructive" closure. 7 upvotes for the answer, favourited twice, viewed 16,117 times. Yes, clearly a matter that is of no import. We need a process to vote OUT moderators for pulling this kind of stunt.

Comment: Annoying that I can't provide this as a late answer... see this link https://www.sqlshack.com/file-validation-in-sql-server-with-xp_fileexist/ for 2017+ using `sys.dm_os_file_exists` if you need to do something inline in a function e.g.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
 CREATE TABLE ResultSet (Directory varchar(200))

 INSERT INTO ResultSet
 EXEC master.dbo.xp_subdirs 'c:\'

 Select * FROM ResultSet where Directory = 'testing'
```

Will return a list of sub directories, you can then check the contents of the list.

Comment: how do I go about selecting from this table tho? i ran the command and i see the table but how do I go about querying it?

Comment: I'd suggest using a temp table instead, so you don't end up with a static table floating around. 

CREATE TABLE #ResultSet (Directory varchar(200)) 

INSERT INTO #ResultSet 
EXEC master.dbo.xp_subdirs 'c:\' 

If Exists (Select * From #ResultSet where Directory = 'testing') Begin 
# Do stuff here 
End 

If you need to do this multiple times over a block of code, create the temp table at the very beginning of the code and then truncate it after each time you use it - slightly optimizes the code to avoid reallocation each time.

Comment: Use this below code:
`code`
DECLARE @BackupDestination nvarchar(500) = N'C:\testing\';
DECLARE @DirectoryExists int;

EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist @BackupDestination, @DirectoryExists OUT;
IF @DirectoryExists = 0
EXEC master.sys.xp_create_subdir @BackupDestination;

Comment: Do we know if this *master.dbo.xp_subdirs*  feature also works for network mapped drives? When I tried on a network mapped drive, I got 'The system cannot find the path specified.' Thanks!

Comment: @Jie The reason for that is that the process identity of SQL Server does not have access to the network drive