# Folder Exists or not in Sql server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can you please help me to give the logic for finding folders in specified drive. As an example below:

```
Declare @NewDrive varchar(1)
Set @NewDrive = 'C'
DECLARE @StringValue varchar(2000)
SET @StringValue = 'C:\Drive1\Folder1\db3.ndf'
```

I need to find whether folders in `@StringValue` exist in `@NewDrive` or not. If not should create it.

`@StringValue` can have many folders.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check if a directory exists using SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765911/how-do-i-check-if-a-directory-exists-using-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you have an in-built function for it, but I found a way through this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740000/check-for-file-exists-or-not-in-sql-server), that is by creating a function;

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_FileExists(@path varchar(512))
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @result INT
     EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist @path, @result OUTPUT
     RETURN cast(@result as bit)
END;
GO
```

Once the function is created, you can just proceed as follows;

```
Declare @cmdpath nvarchar(60)
If Not EXISTS (select dbo.fn_FileExists(filename) from dbo.YourTable)
Begin

 // Create folder
 exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @cmdpath

End
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You can not call procedures in functions. It's because functions can't change anything, they are read-only access.