# How can i check file existence

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code to update `docPath` field, I need help on how to check the existence of a file before running the update statement or update only if the file exist in the directory otherwise skip

```
INSERT INTO DocPath(itemId,docPath)
SELECT 
  itemId,
  '\\ABC-SERVER\Data\PRODUCTION\VAULT\2500000 - 2599999 \PDF\''
   +[WITESTCO].[dbo].[WIITEMX].[itemId]
   +'.pdf'  as docPath
   FROM [WITESTCO].[dbo].[WIITEMX]
   WHERE 
      itemId like '2500%' or itemId like '2501%' ;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check for file exists or not in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740000/check-for-file-exists-or-not-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Create a function like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_FileExists(@path varchar(512))
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @result INT
     EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist @path, @result OUTPUT
     RETURN cast(@result as bit)
END;
GO
```

And use the function like this

```
IF dbo.fn_FileExists('MyPath') = 1
INSERT INTO DocPath(itemId,docPath)
SELECT itemId,'MyPath' ...;
```

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740000/check-for-file-exists-or-not-in-sql-server)

Comment: Isn't it possible that the file could be removed after the function is called but before the `INSERT` statement is processed?

Comment: Of course it is possible, but as I know it is impossible to lock the file to being removed from the database transaction.

Comment: In that case, the original problem can still exist.  Would it not be better in this case to handle the error?

Comment: The same thing can happen even after the insert statement completes. For example we check the existence of a file, it exists, we inserted a row, then someone deletes that file (lets say after 5 mins).