# How to do Bulk insert into microsoft sql server from IntelliJ IDEA and Mac?

Tags: sql, sql-server, macos, docker, intellij-idea

I am running MS SQL Server 2017 in Docker on Mac OSX. I was able to connect from IntelliJ IDEA via Data source. Now, I want to do `BULK INSERT` to load 2+ million rows into DB.

Bulk insert from SQL Server documentation I am trying to adapt:

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[SOCKS]
FROM 'mssql.csv'
WITH (FORMAT='CSV');
```

I constantly get this error:

> [S0001][4860] Cannot bulk load. The file "mssql.csv" does not exist or
> you don't have file access rights.

As far as I read responses on StackOverflow and SQL Server it relates to file access.

My file privileges look:

```
$ ls -lt
-rw-r--r--  1 dmytro  staff       1049 Jun 23 10:37 mssql.csv
```

- I read about the mechanism of checking the path via [SQL Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740000/check-for-file-exists-or-not-in-sql-server#11740400) but couldn't make it work.
- I tried the full path for the file in Unix and Windows format such `/User/name/mssql.csv` and `\\User\name\mssql.csv` and got the same issue as one above.

Am I doing anything wrong? How to do a bulk insert in this case?

Comment: Try with full path of the `'mssql.csv'`

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam I updated question, the full path is the first thing I tried.

Comment: Is the csv file is in the container or in the mac machine?

Comment: Does the sql server have that drive mapped? That was a problem I ran into when trying to use a `BULK INSERT`... The server didn't know the network drive where the file was hangin' around.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam It is on Mac machine. Should I mount the file system somehow? Not sure how to do it though.

Comment: @DmytroChasovskyi yes as per the document the file should be on the server [BULK INSERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)