# SQL Server cursor for file exists check

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which have the details including `file_path`, `datafilename` etc.

The complete file path is the combination of `file_path` and `datafilename`. I need to create a cursor to check the file exists or not..

If the file exists, I need to update the flag column with Y else N.

Please help me.

Comment: you can find reference in the link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740000/check-for-file-exists-or-not-in-sql-server

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share more details on what you have tried, sample code, and where you are facing a problem. This question is open ended, please read posting rules https://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error

Answer (score 0):

I have incorporated the reference provided in comment ([Check for file exists or not in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740000/check-for-file-exists-or-not-in-sql-server)) in cursor, please use your table name

```
DECLARE @file_path nvarchar(200) ,@datafilename nvarchar(200)  

DECLARE FileExist_cursor CURSOR FOR     
SELECT file_path,datafilename  
FROM table  

OPEN FileExist_cursor    

FETCH NEXT FROM FileExist_cursor     
INTO @file_path,@datafilename    

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0    
BEGIN    

 DECLARE @result INT
 DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(400)=@file_path+@datafilename

 exec  master.dbo.xp_fileexist @path,@result OUTPUT

 update  table
 set flag = case when @result='1' then 'Y' else 'N' end
 WHERE 
 file_path = @file_path
 and datafilename    = @datafilename
  
 FETCH NEXT FROM FileExist_cursor     
 INTO @file_path,@datafilename    

END     
CLOSE FileExist_cursor;    
DEALLOCATE FileExist_cursor;
```